# click event need to fire only once

Tags: jquery

Event has occured many times when we click a function

```
$(document).one("click", "#calemonth", function() {
    var clyear = $("#yearpicker").find("option:selected").text();
    console.log(clyear);
    $("#datepickercal").datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'yy'
    });
    var date = new Date();
    var n = date.getFullYear();
    calYear = date.getFullYear();
    var datArray = [];
    var yearOptions1 = $("#yearpickr");
    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        datArray.push(calYear);
        calYear++;
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < datArray.length; i++) {
        options += '<option value= "' + datArray[i] + '">' + datArray[i] + '</option>';
    }
    yearOptions1.html(options);
    yearOptions1.val(clyear);
});
```

Need to fire single time when a click a function

Comment: Deduce by creating a minimal working example.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a flag initialized to false. And once the function is called you can set it to true.

```
 var clicked = false;
    $(document).one("click", "#calemonth", function() {
    if(!clicked)
    {
    var clyear = $("#yearpicker").find("option:selected").text();
            console.log(clyear);
            $("#datepickercal").datepicker({
                dateFormat: 'yy'
            });
            var date = new Date();
            var n = date.getFullYear();
            calYear = date.getFullYear();
            var datArray = [];
            var yearOptions1 = $("#yearpickr");
            for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                datArray.push(calYear);
                calYear++;
            }
            for (var i = 0; i < datArray.length; i++) 
            {
                options += '<option value= "' + datArray[i] + '">' + datArray[i] + 
                '</option>';
            }
            yearOptions1.html(options);
            yearOptions1.val(clyear);
        });

        clicked = true; 
    }
```